# Laravel/Mysql polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm struggling finding the best way to define this relationship, having this models:

```
Event:
id
name
...

User:
id
name
password
group_id
...

Tmpuser:
id
name
...

Group:
id
name

Attendance:
event_id
attended
```

Basically i have an event that can be attended by users and tmpusers. but i need to "register" all the users from a group. i'm struggling definig which fields do i need on attendance to successfully reference the users, tmpuser and groups who attended to the event.  i'm thinking that adding a "remote_id" and "remote_type" fields to attendance is enough to achieve  what i want.

I'm also trying to make this "laravel eloquent compatible", but the closest way to do it is using polymorphic relationships, but those works on the other way of what i want.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

thank you in advance

Comment: Go for Polymorphic. It suits best.